# how to package a NON electron MSI file with Electron application?

Tags: electron, windows-installer, packaging, electron-builder

I have a situation where when a user installs my electron application, i need to actually install 2 applications:  my app + a separate windows MSI that will be included as a part of my application artifacts.

I'm very new to Electron and I just learned a little about electron-builder.  I don't have to use electron-builder for the packaging piece - am open to any suggestions.
Right now... just to see if this can be accomplished, I've created a very simple Electron application that uses the desktopCapturer library to do some simple av stuff.  So I don't really have code to post per se - i can if need be.
But i'm looking for some broad strokes re: an approach / libraries to use etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the separate MSI you mention is distributed as a prerequisite. i.e. your main installer of the app will install it only if it is not already present on the machine.

You can do this with any serious setup authoring tool for Windows. For example here is how you can achieve this with Advanced Installer:

[- Create an MSI package for an Electron application](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/electron-msi-installer.html)
[- configure a prerequisite](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html#prerequisites)

While building an MSI for the electron application can be achieved using the [free edition](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html), for adding prerequisites you would need a license for the Professional edition (you can evaluate this functionality with a trial download before buying).

*Disclaimer. I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*